# OpenGL tune from one color to another

Tags: opengl

I have made a small particle system. What I now would like to do is have the particles fade from one color to another during it's life time. For example from black to white or Yellow to Red.

I use the [`glColor()` functions](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glColor.xml) to set the color of the particle.

How do I do this?

Comment: are you using glut and which version of opengl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to blende the colors by your self:

calculate the blend factor between 0 and 1 and mix the  colors

```
float blend = lifeTime / maxLifeTime;
float red = (destRed * blend) + (srcRed * (1.0 - blend));
float green = (destGreen * blend) + (srcGreen * (1.0 - blend));
float blue = (destBlue * blend) + (srcBlue * (1.0 - blend));
```

regards
ron

Comment: What is nextRed, nextGreen, nextBlue?

Comment: Current is the source color and next stand for the destination color. I use this code in a rainbow color scale.

Comment: Tested this now and it worked exactly like I wanted it to. Thanks.